# How to insert resume into my sqlite database

Tags: android

How would I insert resume into my `SQLite` database after fetching? I am trying to upload a resume from my file but could not fetch like images.

```
prof_resume_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent resumePickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            resumePickerIntent.setType("demodoc/*");
            startActivityForResult(resumePickerIntent, idIntentID2);    

        }
});
```

Comment: Checkout the following link. It talks about using SQLite as a document store. https://www.sqlite.org/appfileformat.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably the better way is not to insert some textual/document or ohter file (I guess it is what you calling "resume") but to store it as a file (on SD card) and to store a path to that file (probably the resumePickerIntent retuns that path already) and some name (as a string to display that file in a list) in sqlite. So its about storing of 2 Text fields.